# What key do browsers use to encrypt HTTPS requests to preloaded HSTS sites?

Tags: https, hsts

As far as I know, HTTPS requests are regular HTTP requests encrypted with the public key provided by the server during the initial handshake.

I have been reading about HSTS but have not been able to find anything related to the public key of sites that are in preloaded HSTS lists. Are the public keys of these sites also preloaded? Or is this key sent by the server on initial handshake like in any HTTPS request?

Comment: The statements is at a minimum vastly simplified: *"HTTPS requests are regular HTTP requests encrypted with the public key provided by the server during the initial handshake"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this key sent by the server on initial handshake like in any HTTPS request?

Yes. HSTS just says “always use HTTPS for this domain so automatically correct any http:// calls to https:// before it is sent”.

It says nothing about how that HTTPS connection is set up, which is done through the usual manner.